# How can I pass a parameter to a method when I start a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I would like to pass a parameter to a method when I start it in a thread.

Also I want to do this in the context of a for loop for k=0 until k=10, for example.

Additionally I want each thread to be independent of each other. So far I have this:

`for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)`
`{`
`new Thread(() => Method2(list[k])).Start();`
`}`

Where Method2 is supposed to do some processing, and is defined as follows(the body is unimportant, it basically creates and writes to a file):

```
public static void Method2(string SYM)
```

Somehow when I run the code, I do have three threads created, but the parameter passed to each thread seems to be only the list[2] parameter for all three. I expected each thread to have list[0] list[1] list[3] as parameters respectively.

Comment: new Thread((obj) => Method2(list[(int)obj)).Start(k);

Comment: Or... new Thread((obj) => Method2((string)obj)).Start(list[k]);

Comment: I think the problem is that the variable k is shared between threads. Try `foreach( int k in Enumerable.Range( 0, 3 ) )`

Comment: Why specifically do you want to use threads rather than tasks?

Comment: Are you intentionally "setting and forgetting" each `Thread` you create?

Comment: Tasks are superior to threads in just about every way. I would suggest you not use the Thread class at all

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution to this problem would be to use `Parallel.ForEach`.

```
static void Main( string[ ] _ )
{
    var list = new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };
    Parallel.ForEach( list, value => Method2( value ) );
}
```

Here is another solution using `Task`'s (setting and forgetting).

```
static void Main( string[ ] _ )
{
    var list = new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };            
    for ( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
    {
        var index = i;
        // Set and forget.
        Task.Run( ( ) => Method2( list[ index ] ) );                                
    }
}
```

And here is another solution using `Task`'s but this time you `await` for each of the `Task`'s to complete.

```
static async Task Main( string[ ] _ )
{
    var list = new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };
    var tasks = new List<Task>( list.Count );
    for ( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
    {
        var index = i;
        // Set and forget.
        tasks.Add( Task.Run( ( ) => Method2( list[ index ] ) ) ); 
    }

    await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
}
```

If you don't like that and want to stick with your solution then you can capture the `i` variable locally in the `for` loop.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
{
    var index = i;
    new Thread( ( ) => Method2( list[ index ] ) ).Start( );
}
```

Each `Thread` will have its own copy of the `index` variable, as opposed to each `Thread` sharing a reference to the `i` variable (which is what you're currently doing).

Your `for` loop is finishing before the first `Thread` has started; so when one of the `Thread`'s finally starts it sees the last value that `i` was set to (in your case `3`).

If you don't believe me run the below code.

```
static void Main( string[ ] _ )
{       
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        new Thread( ( ) => Console.WriteLine( $"{i}" ) ).Start( );
        Thread.Sleep( 1500 );
    }            
    Console.ReadLine( );
 }
```

You *should* see the values, `0`, `1`, `2` printed to the console.
Now, run this code (and note that I removed the `Thread.Sleep`:

```
static void Main( string[ ] _ )
{       
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        new Thread( ( ) => Console.WriteLine( $"{i}" ) ).Start( );
    }            
    Console.ReadLine( );
}
```

You *should* see the values, `3`, `3`, `3` printed to the console.

Comment: `Each invocation of Method2 will be done is a separate thread.` is not 100% true.